# Is there a way to filter a table based on criteria from another table in Power BI using DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have two tables, Scores and Accounts.

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 120 |
| 2 | 150 |
| 3 | 100 |

| ID | Account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Account 1 |
| 2 | Account 2 |
| 3 | Account 3 |

I also have 4 measures that calculate the quartile percentile for all of the scores in the Scores table. I was wondering if it was possible to have a measure that concatenates the accounts into one line if their score is, for example, greater than the Quartile 1 measure. For example, if quartile 1 is 110, then I want a measure that would give me "Account 1, Account 2". Is this possible?

Comment: your sample data not clearly explain the column "quartile 1". Please add your expected output to make the requirement understand clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get your result by implementing the following measure, assuming you have a relationship between the two tables.

```
Accounts GT Q1 = 
CONCATENATEX(
    FILTER(
        Scores,
        Scores[Scores] > [Quartile 1]
    ),
    RELATED( Accounts[Account] ),
    ", "
)
```

**Output**

[image]

There may be a simpler way. Let me know if that worked.